# Reduce the size of Flash memory embedded cpp

Tags: c++, embedded, flash-memory

After a lot of research i could not find any solution to my question (if i did i woudln't be here ...)
I'm looking for solutions that permits me to reduce the flash memory used by my program.

I'm programming an embedded c++ programm and when i Flash my electronic card  in release mode everything is fine cause it doesn't overflow the space of the flash memory, but that is not the case when i do it in Debug mode... I want to know if it is possible to find functions (my goal is to do it without reducing the code) that could reduce Flash memory.I already thought about defragmentation but I don't find how to do it in embedded even though i don't even know if i can ...  I also tried the -Os cmd from gcc but without any big success

So I'm taking any advices or support and i'll be there at any question about my issue ;)

Thanks !

Comment: Debug builds are typically large. Have you tried separating the debug symbols from the binary?

Comment: @Joe: Symbols tables typically don't go into embedded flash.

Comment: True, but I know nothing about his system at the moment.

Comment: Your question is far too broad. Which platform? What kind of Flash? How is the code organised? Why not use a device with larger Flash for development? If you are already at the edge of Flash, you might have problems later with updates.

Comment: @Joe: That's what comments are for: ask for clarification/narrowing. Or vote to close if the question is not salvageable. (like this one).

Comment: Try C instead of C++?

Comment: Debug mode may add extra code for single stepping and/or watching variables.  Release mode is the only one that matters as that is the one you ship, so you should be testing the shipping binary not some other binary (debug).

Comment: sometimes optimizing for speed (-O2 for example with gcc) can result in a smaller binary than for size, go figure.  Depends on the compiler, so try both.  Examine the output of the compiler...

Comment: @Olaf my question was not that far, in my case it didn't depend on the hard part, i was looking for solution in softprogramming, and so i had :) 
My goal was to keep having the same flash memory size so i couldn't add another KB of memory

Comment: @old_timer I was in -O0, the solution was to optimize with -Os
Thanks !

Comment: @ben `-Os` will make the code near undebuggable. As you explicitly ask about debug code, your comment does not make sense.

Comment: your comment said you tried -Os without success, and now you say it was successful?  so the -Os test didnt happen or you thought you had tried it but didnt?  (or were looking at elf file size not actual program size?)

Comment: actually my program takes 84kb in flash and is debuggable, with -Os

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Look at your map file.  Is there something there you don't
   expect? Functions you aren't expecting (like floating point, or
   exception handling, etc.) or something unreasonably large?
2. Turn on optimization except for the file you're interested in.
3. Make sure you've actually got optimizations turned on (look at the build log and ensure that you've got -Os being passed to each compile step)
4. Consider link time optimizations, but don't expect miracles

Welcome to embedded programming.  90% of the job is figuring out how to stuff the never ending requirements into the memory available.  Rinse and repeat.

Comment: Hi ! 

well .. thanks for your time and answers, Russ Schultz, your third step gave me the solution, i checked my makefile and i had one Flag that wasn't in -Os and now i'm using less than half of my flash memory ... that -Os is powerful haha.
Thanks again

Comment: 1. should not be a problem if no unnecessary functions are linked - which should be the default anyway. 2 -4 actually defy debugging. 2) is problematic with OOP (which C++ implies) code, the others make code typically undebuggable.

Comment: @olaf  #1 is there specifically to ensure you aren't linking unnecessary functions (plus traditional linking won't cull unused functions in object files that have other symbols required).   #2-#4...welcome to embedded programming:  where jtag is a luxury and memory for the entire project to be compiled with -g is a pipe dream.